# Set extended AbstractNode.java with auto expanded child nodes as default

Tags: java, openide

I extended and use org.openide.nodes.AbstracNode.java class as CategoryNode.java in my codes.
I want to set CategoryNode.java and it's child as default expanded tree nodes(Auto expanded)when i render the nodes in UI component.
Any one can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's a clear question and it doesn't need any more description and code sample.
I just want to know how can i set OpenIDE AbstractNode as default expanded mode.

Comment: Finally, i found solution.
We can use openide TreeView.java class.